# Maven build fails with failsafe plugin

Tags: junit5, spring-test, maven-failsafe-plugin, junit-jupiter

I am trying to build my project and run the test by using junit5 and maven failsafe plugin for integration tests.

If I run my test by using

> mvn failsafe:integration-test

it runs all the integration tests.

When I run

> maven install

failsafe plugin fails with integration tests with error. But surfire plugin works normally. I receive following error for failsafe plugin:

```
      TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
      ...
      ...
      Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mypackage/service/MyObject
```

My pom with failsafe plugin looks like:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <useModulePath>false</useModulePath>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I am using junit jupiter version 5.8.2. I tried to use older versions as it was suggested in other posts but it did not help. Any idea what can be wrong here ?

Comment: Your include may be missing two stars. Apart from that, you’ll have to show your folder hierarchy and test class names to provide more info on what’s really going on.

Comment: There are two starts actually, I forgot to add. My tests follows xxxIT.java convention.  And the tests are under  app/test/java/mypackage/. Pom file above is pom file of the app module.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and [this tip](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/issues/1422) solved it for me.
Basically you need to set `<useModulePath>false</useModulePath>` on the failsafe plugin config.

I solved it by including this snippet on my pom.xml:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <useModulePath>false</useModulePath>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*IT.java</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```